# Is TDRS-M (TDRS-13) where it's supposed to be?

Tags: artificial-satellite, communication-satellite, geosynchronous, tdrss

**edit:** Status 2018-Jan-01 inclination still about 7 degrees, location still not listed in Wikipedia.

---

[This question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23217/12102) got me thinking about the location of active TDRS satellites, and the newest addition [TDRS-M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TDRS-M) which does not yet have a fixed GEO longitude listed in Wikipedia's [List of TDRS satellites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TDRS_satellites).

N2YO [shows it over the pacific](https://www.n2yo.com/satellite/?s=42915) at about 150° W in an apparently close-to-geosynchronous orbit with an inclination of about 7 degrees, which is also reflected in the TLE shown in [Celestrak](https://celestrak.org/cgi-bin/TLE.pl?CATNR=42915).

Is this the final planned location, or will it continue to move to a target longitude? Is there a plan to reduce the inclination closer to zero?

[image]

```
TDRS 13                 
1 42915U 17047A   17275.30862482  .00000108  00000-0  00000+0 0  9993
2 42915   6.9726 332.4220 0005466 324.9709  34.9480  1.00272650   498
```

[image]

Comment: @MBM after reading the link in your [comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/25325/can-they-watch-tv-at-the-south-pole-what-satellites-are-used-for-data-comms-a?noredirect=1#comment73377_25325) I realized that you can probably easilly answer this question (hint: yes it is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `Tracking and Data Relay Satellite System (TDRSS)` option on Celestrak's NORAD Two-Line Element Sets [Current Data TLE page](https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/) I've compiled current TLE inclinations for "on line" TDRS spacecraft:

```
Spacecraft     inc(degs)
TDRS 3          14.4405
TDRS 5          14.5306
TDRS 6          14.0861
TDRS 7          15.0545
TDRS 8           7.9573
TDRS 9           5.8274
TDRS 10          5.5187
TDRS 11          5.0141
TDRS 12          5.6613
```

While not included on that page, TDRS-13 can still be found in Celestrak:

```
TDRS 13          6.7494
```

Considering that:

- `TDRS-M` has now been renamed `TDRS 13`, and...
- ...according to [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26268/12102) has officially entered into service.
- its inclination is still close to 7 degrees (and TDRS are in general always inclined).
- its longitude it's still near 150W.

It is very likely that *yes, it is where it is supposed to be*.

[image]

**above:** Screen shot from [N2Y0](http://www.n2yo.com/?s=42915).