# Where can I find data on satellite orbits?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, artificial-satellite, trajectory, communication-satellite

I'm an enthusiast who'd like access to satellite orbital data to simulate / plot trajectories of manmade satellites (of any kind) on my home computer. Where's the best place for me to find this kind of data? Understandably, this is a big subject so if you have any learning materials to recommend, I'd be appreciative of that too. (For context I just got my BSc in physics, so something around that level please)

Thanks for reading!

Comment: For starters: If you're looking for positioning data, you can start simple by downloading the two-line element (TLE) off CelesTrak, and if you want to avoid any coding, you can simply paste it into STK's free licensed SGP4 propagator. Then, you can access their Reports and Graphs Manager, and output the Positions, Velocities, classical elements, and any other forms of data you might like :)

Comment: You may find two-line elements on CelesTrak here:
https://celestrak.com/NORAD/elements/

Comment: related: [https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25958/12102](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/25958/how-can-i-plot-a-satellites-orbit-in-3d-from-a-tle-using-python-and-skyfield) and I went [crazy here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/37454/12102). Skyfield automatically downloads the TLEs if you like or you can get them yourself as SamLow explains. For spacecraft not in Earth Orbit you can [get them from Horizons](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25357/12102). For *learning materials* I recommend just start reading questions and answers here, that's how I learned!

Comment: @SamLow Please don't answer questions in comments.  If you have an answer (which evidently you do), please post it as an answer.

Comment: http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13488/ might be a starting point